# 6 - No content displaying though content is there

Tags: 6

I'm new to drupal, moved from WordPress. I'm trying to get a local install of a client site working. I have the site running normally but no content wants to show.

The content is there, I can see it in the backend and on, say, the blog page it has the right amount of paginated links. Plus the markup and css are correct. The div is empty though.

I've disabled memcache, that might be it, plus all things on the net I could find.
- truncated the cache tables
- run update.php
- tried creating a new view, same issue

plus some others I can't think of right now.

Any help with debug pointers would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This issue is still open.

Answer (score 1):

This can be of due to many reasons. Check one of these,

1. Go to *configuration/system/site information*, Make sure, you have correct number of posts and front page. [Number of posts on front page ]
2. When you add content, then, make sure, you click on publishing option and click on 'published' checkbox. You can check the content is published or not, by making a menu link of it.
3. If these are okay, then, please check by changing the theme, may be your theme page is broken or something. Go to *appearance* and select new theme.

Make sure, you flush your system, cache and try.

Comment: Where do I find configuration/system/site information ?

Comment: is it an admin menu?

Comment: This is admin menu. You have in admin, header configuration, you click on that, then you can see list of system menu, and there u can find site information.

Comment: Sharing my knowledge is my pleasure. Please feel free to share your knowledge you have.

Comment: I tried the above, home is set and content is published.

I tried changing the theme to garland and the same issue happens, looks like content should be there, pagination is there, classes are there but nothing in div

Comment: did u try editing, page.tpl.php from the theme. if not then, it should display your content. i am sure that should. can you show me some screenshots.

Comment: Haha, I just looked at page.tpl.php and it has the first 5 or so columns are missing in the file! 

I got the previous dev to send the site code, so I'll take it up with him.

Thanks again Suresh.

Comment: How do I resolve the issue on SE?

Comment: SE, can you elaborate?

Comment: On Stack Exchange, how do I resolve this post?

Comment: I would suggest you to host the site by making any subdomain and using free hosting. Then, you can show the live demo of the problem you are facing.

Comment: click on the greyed out checkmark under the rating of the correct answer and turn it green if you wish to accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious and is also a stab in the dark but have you tried comparing with the live site if all the enabled/disabled modules are also enabled/disabled on your local install? Something like Blog page might not show anything due to views/panels being disabled?

Comment: I'm guessing the same modules are set as I imported the db from the live site. And a quick glance seems to support this.